# Apache Oltu tutorials/tips

Tags: apache, oauth-2.0, oltu

I have a task to integrate the OAuth 2.0 protocol on an API by using Apache Oltu. Since I can't understand the examples on the website http://oltu.apache.org/index.html , has someone experience with this and could he give me tips/tutorials how could I implement it?

Thanks!

Comment: hi ivaylo have what are you looking exactly for? how about try to write to user@oltu.apache.org ?

Comment: Hi Ivayalo, what you need to do create client which consume Oauth 2 API or you need to impl REST API?